# WMware virtual machine cannot connect to internet

Tags: virtual-machine, debian, dns, internet-connection

I have to use virtual machine located at https://crypto.stanford.edu/cs155/hw_and_proj/pp1/boxes-2.3.tar.bz2. It is a Debian without any GUI. I run it with default configuration. I am able to make ssh from host machine to this virtual machine. Also I can ping from virtual machine to host machine but I can't ping any adress from internet. I have to connect this machine to internet. Is there any solution? Thanks.

> cat /proc/version

outputs

> Linux version 2.6.32-5-686 (Debian 2.6.32-41squeeze2) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Mon Mar 26 05:20:33 UTC 2012

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: I can ping 8.8.8.8 but can't ping any website.

Comment: Please correct the title: **VMware**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first made sure that both host and guest can ping each other. Once that's done, I configured `resolv.conf` using the following command:

```
# sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and added two lines:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the VMware client network card is set to NAT. 
[image: NAT]

Comment: It is set to NAT at default configuration.

Comment: Then it has the same access as the host. Does your host machine have internet access?

Comment: Yes. Virtual machine can ping IP adresses not URLs.

Comment: OHHHHH, then you have a DNS issue

Comment: Is there any solutions for this. I am unexperienced to Linux without any GUI and console commands.

Answer (score 0):

Networking is running since you can ping a public ip address.  Your DNS is not working correctly or is being blocked.

Verify you have a working DNS.

> less > /etc/resolv.conf

Find any problems with traceroute

> traceroute www.google.com

Comment: It prints out a lot of ~ symbols there is not ip adresses.

Answer (score 0):

This virtual machine is configured to use Stanford's DNS servers. I edited etc/resolv.conf and changed DNS servers to GoogleDNS. Now virtual machine can connect through URL.